# change input type on focus in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I want to change the type of input from text to date in vue 3. Is there a way to make this code works?

```
<input type="text" name="insurance_expires_at" v-model="form.provider.insurance_expires_at"
     :validation="$v.provider.insurance_expires_at" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
     @focus=" this.type = 'date' "/>
```

Comment: You may need to provide more context as to your v-model and validation schema. However, I can try to help flesh something re-usable out in a sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a state variable to dynamically keep the input's type value. Then, update it to `date` on focus, and revert it to `text` on blur (if you wish).

A simple implementation using Vue 3 and composition API could be:

```html
<template>
  <input :type="inputType" @focus="onFocus" @blur="onBlur">
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const inputType = ref('text');

function onFocus() {
  inputType.value = 'date';
}

function onBlur() {
  inputType.value = 'text'; // Optional, to revert
}

</script>
```

As it is obvious, you can dynamically bind other props (like placeholder and validation) and adjust them in the `onFocus` event; as it is done for the `type` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above, I tried to replicate with options API:

```
<template>
  <input
    :type="inputType"
    name="insurance_expires_at"
    :placeholder="inputType === 'text' ? 'MM/DD/YYYY' : 'YYYY-MM-DD'"
    @focus="changeToDatePicker"
    @blur="changeToText"
  />

  <!-- Complete template below, removed v-model and validation to avoid errors -->

  <!-- <input
    :type="inputType"
    name="insurance_expires_at"
    v-model="form.provider.insurance_expires_at"
    :validation="$v.provider.insurance_expires_at"
    :placeholder="inputType === 'text' ? 'MM/DD/YYYY' : 'YYYY-MM-DD'"
    @focus="changeToDatePicker"
    @blur="changeToText"
  /> -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputType: "text",
      form: {
        provider: {
          insurance_expires_at: "",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeToDatePicker(event) {
      this.inputType = "date";
      // Format to datepicker
      const dateParts = this.form.provider.insurance_expires_at.split("/");
      if (dateParts.length === 3) {
        this.form.provider.insurance_expires_at = `${dateParts[2]}-${dateParts[0]}-${dateParts[1]}`;
      }
    },
    changeToText() {
      this.inputType = "text";
      // Format to preferred string
      const dateParts = this.form.provider.insurance_expires_at.split("-");
      if (dateParts.length === 3) {
        this.form.provider.insurance_expires_at = `${dateParts[1]}/${dateParts[2]}/${dateParts[0]}`;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Test link: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-https-8j85vd?file=/src/App.vue

Hopefully, this solves your problem.